# Why importing the header file of class 'A' in the source file of class 'B' makes the content of class 'A' defined inside the header file of class 'B'?

Tags: c++, include

Suppose I have a class called `Class`:

`Class.h`:

```
#pragma once

class Class
{
public:

    std::vector<int> x();
};
```

`Class.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Class.h"

std::vector<int> Class::x()
{
    return std::vector<int>();
}
```

I suppose that this code should not compile since `std::vector` isn't defined in `Class.h`. But the code works. It doesn't work if I include the needed headers (in this case it's just `vector`) after including `Class.h`. But as long as the needed headers are imported before the inclusion of `Class.h`, everythig works fine. Also it doesn't work if I try to include `Class.h` somewhere alone and try to use it. So for example this code won't work:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Class.h"

    int main()
    {
        Class c;
        auto x = c.x();

        x.push_back(1);
        x.push_back(2);
        x.push_back(3);

        for (auto i : x)
            std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
```

But if I include the needed headers, It works fine. So in this example, it works if I include the `vector` header (also has to be before the inclusion of `Class.h`):

```
#include <vector>
#include "Class.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Class c;
    auto x = c.x();

    x.push_back(1);
    x.push_back(2);
    x.push_back(3);

    for (auto i : x)
        std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

I'm thinking of `#include` as just copy-pasting. In `Class.h`, no header is being included. How is it possible to say that this function will return an `std::vector` without it being defined? And why including the headers in the source file makes it as if it was included in the header file?

Comment: Think of `#include` as just copy-pasting the referenced file into the enclosing code.  Does that make things clearer?

Comment: Every source file and header file should include what it uses.  Sometimes a forward declaration can be used instead, which is a good alternative in some circumstances.  Although I prefer making header-header files (`*.hh`) which contains forward declarations, and then include those, because I find that it scales better for large projects.

Comment: I'm thinking of ``#include`` as just copy-pasting. In ``Class.h``, no header is being included. How is it possible to say that this function will return an ``std::vector`` without it being defined? And why including the headers in the source file makes it as if it was included in the header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not compile `Class.h`, you compile the cpp file which `#include`s `Class.h`.

If you include the vector header before `Class.h` in `main.cpp`, then, after the preprocessor step, your `main.cpp` file will have the contents of `vector` header, followed by the contents of `Class.h`, followed by other code in `main.cpp`. So the definition of `vector` will be visible in `Class`.

If you compile just the `Class.h` header separately, you will get an error. I advise you always do this to check if your header files have all the necessary headers and can compile without relying on side effects.